# Blackberry Simulator cannot run

Tags: blackberry-simulator

I am building an blackberry app. When I run/debug Project it's giving an error:

[image]

Again and again. I have cleaned the project, restarted eclipse, but nothing changes. Project is working fine, but suddenly this happened!

Answer (score 0):

In your simulator or the JDE installation directory you can find `clean.bat` you can run it from the command prompt. If you just double click it some times it might not run properly. So point to the path of the command.bat of the corresponding JDE simulator directory and run the clean.bat.

Hope this will solve your problem.